# What is the key-derivation used in pdf2, is there a secure option?

Tags: encryption, key-derivation

I recently needed (for legitimate reasons) to crack an encrypted pdf sent by a local bank. It was pdf1.7 and the password was 6 digits. cracking it with John the ripper took no time at all. In fact it was faster than normal waiting for the SMS, which is the way I should have gotten the password but that wasn't working.

I tried to read the spec for pdf1.7 and it seems they have their own very poor key derivation with 50 iterations of MD5. Using AES later for encryption does not help.
Which explains why john the ripper made such short work of the password.

I failed to find matching documentation for pdf2 the latest standard. Is it any better?
If not, Is there a commonly supported document format which employs a strong key derivation? (hey I'll settle for bcrypt or pbkdf2 doesn't have to be scrypt).

Comment: Note that the final part of the post is requesting a software recommendation, which is a rather perpendicular to the question. It's fine if people want to comment on that here, but answers should be considered valid without any recommendation.

Comment: Modern zip implementations use PBKDF2 to derive an AES-CBC key (make sure not to use a legacy format, legacy encrypted zip used bad crypto). I think at least decryption has been natively supported on Windows for ages. Zip encryption only encrypts file contents, not metadata, so don't put confidential information in file names.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I think the idea was to have a document with internal security, so that you don't have to put it into an archive, but I may be wrong of course.

Comment: "Although it is an open standard, one major difference compared with prior versions of PDF is that ISO now holds the copyright to [the PDF specification](https://www.iso.org/standard/75839.html) and thus PDF 2.0 is not freely downloadable." Oh, how lovely :(

Comment: WTF? It's paywalled?! that explains my difficulty in finding an answer.